# Jquery-Validation for Full Name

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using the following code to validate alphabets, but it doesn't allow back space or delete key. Please suggest if you have nay idea. Thanks in advance.

```
$('input#ClientA_FullName').keydown(function (e) {
        if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).match(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g)) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why are you validation the pressed key and not what is actually in the input field?

Comment: What will you do if someone pastes something in the input?

Comment: As @Pehmolelu says but if they simply hold down the key? Why not just validate it onblur or onchange

Comment: Thanks for your reply can any one give me the code?

Comment: My intension is to prevent user to enter anything other than alphabet, rather than giving a validation message. BUt it should allow back space delete tab and space keys

Comment: Please suggest any idea if you have. Thanks all for yr comments

Answer (score 1):

```
Try This
$("#ValuationName").bind("keypress", function (event) {
    if (event.charCode!=0) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution.
Please look at http://jsfiddle.net/Mq7mv/ for a working sample.

You need to change the code as follows:

```
$('input#ClientA_FullName').keydown(function (e) {
if ((e.keyCode != 8 /*backspace*/ || e.keyCode != 46 /*delete*/) &&
String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).match(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g) == null) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Validating on the `keydown` event will certainly work, if that's really what you want to do.  However, there are so many special conditions to the `keydown` event that you're not checking for.  Simply checking for *backspace* and *delete* aren't enough.  There are other keys which you should allow.  For example, left and right arrows, ctrl + x, v, and c (as someone said in the comments above), and even the shift key.  Also, there are conditions, like someone holding down 1 key, which need to be taken into account, because that will only fire a single event.

A better option would be to validate the field on the `blur` event.  This event fires just before the field loses focus (the cursor is moved out of it).  Validating on this event will allow you to check the field's value as a complete name (as, most people will put the name into the field and then go to the next field).  You don't have to capture a whole bunch of special conditions, you just get the value, see if it's valid, and move on.

The code would be much similar to what you have now,

```
$('input#ClientA_FullName').blur(function(e) {
    var val = $(this).val();

    if (val.match(/[^a-z ]/gi)) //you matched an invalid character
    {
        alert("Client A Full Name is invalid");
        return false;
    }
});
```

It might also be worth noting that checking a-z and spaces really isn't a valid check for a "full name" field.  There are plenty of people that have an apostrophe in their name ("O'Brein" for example), hypens (women who get married and hyphenate their name, "Nancy Jones-Smith"), periods ("T.J. Smith"), etc.  Not to mention global names, where you might have character emphasis (umlauts, etc) in the name.  Your validation (and the validation example I gave you) does not allow for these characters, and would make it impossible for these names to be typed into your system.

For a robust name validation system, you need much more than just checking a-z and spaces.  I'd re-evaluate how important getting a name with exactly the right characters is to the functionality of your system.  It's okay to put some onus on the user to input a name correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know any place which has a form that says: Your name is not valid! So why even have validation for that? Instead add length validation. It has to have atleast 1 letter, no max value, or if must, maybe 255 because there are really long names in some countries. If someone does not want to tell his name he can still just type zzzzzzzzzzz. There are so many different alphabets in the world aswell like cyrillic, arabic, chinese. The best is to put just length validation and make mysql_real_escape_string function to prevent SQL injection (If you are using mysql). The Javascript wont protect you. If user wants he may still put just any kind of data to POST. Just save the name as it is but with just SQL injection prevention.